# Can I import contents of a python file written in binary?

Tags: python, import, binary, package

I have a python package which contains multiple .py files. One of these files contains a python list the order of which is vital to the package. I want this particular file to be stored as a binary (to avoid any accidental change in the order) and still be able to import the contents of this file. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify how a .py file in text format might be insecure in terms of list ordering?

Comment: I want the user not be able to change the order of elements in the list. Is it possible to convert a particular file into binary and use it to solve this problem?

Comment: why not just load the contents of that list from a binary file?

Comment: You'd need to write your own encoding\decoding intermediary module between the import call from a script and the original file ???

Comment: What exactly would prevent the user from changing it if it's encoded in a binary format? Instead of changing the order they'll most likely mess up the whole file instead if it's accidental

Comment: You need to encode your data, not the code